# Apply XSLT on XML to filter information based on tag match in same file

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XML and XSLT, I want to filter some information from an XML file. Based on match on some tag values in the XML file.

This is my XML File as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<People>
<Person>
    <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
    <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
    <tag3>not important info</tag3>
    <tag4>not important info</tag4>
    <first-name>Mike</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <number>938387</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">TX</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
        </license>
        <license>
            <number>938387</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">IL</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <appointments>
        <appointment-info>
            <code>5124</code>
            <number>14920329324</number>
            <licensed-states>
                <state>TX</state>
            </licensed-states>
        </appointment-info>
    </appointments>
</Person>
<Person>
    <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
    <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
    <tag3>not important info</tag3>
    <tag4>not important info</tag4>
    <first-name>John</first-name>
    <last-name>Jhonny</last-name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <number>1762539</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">TX</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
        </license>
        <license>
            <number>1762539</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">NY</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <appointments>
        <appointment-info>
            <code>5124</code>
            <number>14920329324</number>
            <licensed-states>
                <state>TX</state>
            </licensed-states>
        </appointment-info>
    </appointments>
</Person>
    <Person>
    <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
    <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
    <tag3>not important info</tag3>
    <tag4>not important info</tag4>
    <first-name>Mike</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <number>17294083</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">IL</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <appointments>
        <appointment-info>
            <code>5124</code>
            <number>14920329324</number>
            <licensed-states>
                <state>IL</state>
            </licensed-states>
        </appointment-info>
    </appointments>
</Person>
<Person>
    <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
    <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
    <tag3>not important info</tag3>
    <tag4>not important info</tag4>
    <first-name>John</first-name>
    <last-name>Jhonny</last-name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <number>840790</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">TX</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
        </license>
        <license>
            <number>840790</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">NY</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
        </license>
        <license>
            <number>840790</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">CA</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <appointments>
        <appointment-info>
            <code>5124</code>
            <number>14920329324</number>
            <licensed-states>
                <state>TX</state>
                <state>NY</state>
            </licensed-states>
        </appointment-info>
    </appointments>
</Person>
</People>
```

What I want to basically do is that, if a Person is licensed in a state for example TX. And has appointment information in that state for example TX, filter that from licenses. If that is the only license information then filter the person.

And the new xml should contain information of required tags. And only Licenses which didn't match with licenses in appointment licenses state. And filtered person who matched all licenses.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<People>
<Person>
    <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
    <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
    <first-name>Mike</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <number>938387</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">IL</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
        </license>
    </licenses>
</Person>
<Person>
    <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
    <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
    <first-name>John</first-name>
    <last-name>Jhonny</last-name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <number>1762539</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">NY</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
        </license>
    </licenses>
</Person>
<Person>
    <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
    <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
    <first-name>John</first-name>
    <last-name>Jhonny</last-name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <number>840790</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">CA</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
        </license>
    </licenses>
</Person>
</People>
```

How to write an XSLT to filter this information. I am using XSLT Version 1.0

Currently I am able to apply this XSLT to get the required tags for transformation.
But I don't know how to filter for Licenses States:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/People">
  <People>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Person"/>
  </People>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="Person">
   <Person>
  <xsl:copy-of select="required-tag1"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="required-tag2"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="first-name"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="last-name"/>
</Person>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most XSLTs, start with an [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) and then override it.

You can filter out the licenses by only overriding a `license` whose `state` matches a `state` in a `licensed-states`.

**XML Input**

```
<People>
    <Person>
        <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
        <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
        <tag3>not important info</tag3>
        <tag4>not important info</tag4>
        <first-name>Mike</first-name>
        <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
        <licenses>
            <license>
                <number>938387</number>
                <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">TX</state>
                <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
            </license>
            <license>
                <number>938387</number>
                <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">IL</state>
                <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
            </license>
        </licenses>
        <appointments>
            <appointment-info>
                <code>5124</code>
                <number>14920329324</number>
                <licensed-states>
                    <state>TX</state>
                </licensed-states>
            </appointment-info>
        </appointments>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
        <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
        <tag3>not important info</tag3>
        <tag4>not important info</tag4>
        <first-name>John</first-name>
        <last-name>Jhonny</last-name>
        <licenses>
            <license>
                <number>1762539</number>
                <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">TX</state>
                <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
            </license>
            <license>
                <number>1762539</number>
                <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">NY</state>
                <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
            </license>
        </licenses>
        <appointments>
            <appointment-info>
                <code>5124</code>
                <number>14920329324</number>
                <licensed-states>
                    <state>TX</state>
                </licensed-states>
            </appointment-info>
        </appointments>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
        <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
        <tag3>not important info</tag3>
        <tag4>not important info</tag4>
        <first-name>Mike</first-name>
        <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
        <licenses>
            <license>
                <number>17294083</number>
                <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">IL</state>
                <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
            </license>
        </licenses>
        <appointments>
            <appointment-info>
                <code>5124</code>
                <number>14920329324</number>
                <licensed-states>
                    <state>IL</state>
                </licensed-states>
            </appointment-info>
        </appointments>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
        <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
        <tag3>not important info</tag3>
        <tag4>not important info</tag4>
        <first-name>John</first-name>
        <last-name>Jhonny</last-name>
        <licenses>
            <license>
                <number>840790</number>
                <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">TX</state>
                <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
            </license>
            <license>
                <number>840790</number>
                <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">NY</state>
                <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
            </license>
            <license>
                <number>840790</number>
                <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">CA</state>
                <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
            </license>
        </licenses>
        <appointments>
            <appointment-info>
                <code>5124</code>
                <number>14920329324</number>
                <licensed-states>
                    <state>TX</state>
                    <state>NY</state>
                </licensed-states>
            </appointment-info>
        </appointments>
    </Person>
</People>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity transform (aka identity template). This will match
    and copy attributes and nodes (element, text, comment and
    processing-instruction) without changing them. Unless a more
    specific template matches, everything will get handled by this
    template.-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--This template will match all "appointments", "tag3", "tag4" element nodes.
    It will also match "license" element nodes that have a child "state"
    element whose value matches a "state" element node that is a child of 
    "licensed-states".
    It will also match the "Person" element node if the number of
    "state" elements that don't have a corresponding "licensed-state"
    is equal to zero. ("filtered person who matched all licenses"
    requirement.)
    Instead of writing 4 individual xsl:templates, I used
    the union "|" operator in the "match" attribute. Since the "xsl:template" is 
    empty, nothing is output or processed further.-->
    <xsl:template match="appointments|license[state=../..//licensed-states/state]|tag3|
    tag4|Person[count(licenses/license[not(state=../..//licensed-states/state)])=0]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<People>
   <Person>
      <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
      <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
      <first-name>Mike</first-name>
      <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
      <licenses>
         <license>
            <number>938387</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">IL</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
         </license>
      </licenses>
   </Person>
   <Person>
      <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
      <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
      <first-name>John</first-name>
      <last-name>Jhonny</last-name>
      <licenses>
         <license>
            <number>1762539</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">NY</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
         </license>
      </licenses>
   </Person>
   <Person>
      <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
      <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
      <first-name>John</first-name>
      <last-name>Jhonny</last-name>
      <licenses>
         <license>
            <number>840790</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">CA</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
         </license>
      </licenses>
   </Person>
</People>
```

If you end up filtering out more nodes than you keep, you can switch it up and do an `xsl:apply-templates` to handle more of the filtering...

**XSLT 1.0** (same output as above)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity transform (aka identity template). This will match
    and copy attributes and nodes (element, text, comment and
    processing-instruction) without changing them. Unless a more
    specific template matches, everything will get handled by this
    template.-->    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--This template will match the "Person" element node. The "xsl:copy"
    creates the new "Person" element. The "xsl:apply-templates" tells
    the processor to apply templates to any attributes (of Person) or
    elements listed in the "select". (Other elements will not be 
    processed.) I used the union operator in the "select" so I wouldn't
    have to write multiple "xsl:apply-templates".-->
    <xsl:template match="Person">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|first-name|last-name|
                required-tag1|required-tag2|licenses"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--This template will match any "license" element nodes that have a child 
    "state" element whose value matches a "state" element node that is a 
    child of "licensed-states". 
    This template will also match the "Person" element node if the number of
    "state" elements that don't have a corresponding "licensed-state"
    is equal to zero. ("filtered person who matched all licenses"
    requirement.)
    Since the "xsl:template" is empty, nothing 
    is output or processed further.-->
    <xsl:template match="license[state=../..//licensed-states/state]|
    Person[count(licenses/license[not(state=../..//licensed-states/state)])=0]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Daniel This works perfect, but I don't understand how it works, can you explain me. I am new to XML/XSLT and want to learn. I saw some tutorials online and they only teach basic and some looping. The above solution, I am guessing it copies the entire XML and then

 <xsl:template match="appointments|license[state=//licensed-states/state]|tag3|tag4"/>

Is doing a match for the Licenses tag and you specify all the tags that you don't want to be copied? I don't understand how is <appointments>tag dropped?

Thank you very much for your help, appreciate it. What resources should I use to learn XSLT?

Comment: @Aniks - I added comments to the XSLT. Hopefully they make sense. I would recommend Michael Kay's XSLT books. They are a great resource. I also like the specs (XSLT and XPath) themselves. Jeni Tennison's XSLT pages are handy (http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/) as well as the quick reference cards from Mulberry Tech (http://www.mulberrytech.com/quickref/index.html). I'd also recommend a good editor (http://www.oxygenxml.com/) for writing XSLT as well. It makes it so much easier. Also, searching here on SO will provide tons of examples on how to handle just about anything in XSLT.

Comment: The solution you guided me works for xml files with two person information, when I am trying to test it with more persons, it fails. And all the <licenses /> are empty except the last one. I don't understand why this is happening, will you be able to guide me anything on this.

Comment: @Aniks - The reason all the `licenses` elements were empty was because the XSLT was looking at all of the `licensed-states`; not just the `licensed-states` for the current `Person`. I also added a match to filter a `Person` if all licenses were matched. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. This solution helped me a lot to learn and works great for me. Do you experience working with XSLT to convert and XML to CSV.